# Adding Custom Link on my Medium Publication's Logo

Tags: redirect, medium.com-publishing-api

Hi I'm trying to add a custom link to send my visitor back to my website via my publication's logo on medium
([See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5oiC.png))
and so far no good. I checked on Medium's documentation and it sends me to [this link](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214110127-About-custom-domains) and I believe that this link is not what I'm looking for because this will only make the Medium use that domain to load the publication and will not load me back to my website because in the first place this will use the domain and what I want is to allow my readers to click on the logo found on the header back to my website. So I was wondering if this is possible and if there are undocumented articles regarding this?